# Magento 2 Issue with Minicart product price when price is set Including tax

Tags: checkout, catalog, mini-cart

**Issue:** Minicart is showing price excluding Taxes even if it is set in the backend to show product price including taxes

**Backend Settings:** Product price is set to show including taxes: it is working fine on products listing, details pages, check out and cart pages except for mini cart

[image]

I tried to debug knockout response even there I can not find the option to show pricing including taxes. How can I show the price in minicart with taxes?

[image]